# Why doesn't UIVisualEffectView work in SwiftUI context menus?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a relatively simple view, and I am trying to get `UIVisualEffectView` to work when used within a context menu.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
            Image("Flower")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            
            VStack {
                Text("Line 1")
                Text("Line 2")
            }
            .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
            .background(BlurView())
        }
        .contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
            Text("Menu Item 1")
        }))
    }
}

struct BlurView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var style: UIBlurEffect.Style = .systemMaterial
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIVisualEffectView {
        return UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: style))
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
        uiView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
    }
}
```

When the view loads it works great, but when the context menu is activated the whole blur just disappears.

[image: Initial view]
[image: Context menu active]

Hopefully there's a workaround or I'll just have to use a completely different overlay until this is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way how the `contextMenu` interferes with the underlying view.

If you don't want this behaviour, you can attach the `contextMenu` to an invisible overlay, so the underlying view will remain *untouched*:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
            Image("testImage")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)

            VStack {
                Text("Line 1")
                Text("Line 2")
            }
            .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
            .background(BlurView())
        }
        .overlay(
            Color.clear
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
                    Text("Menu Item 1")
                }))
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to implement this into my app but it doesn't really work. I just get a blurred background with a context menu attached to an invisible square with a shadow.

Comment: @EliottRobson That's the best I could come up with. Looks like the `contextMenu` interferes with every kind of a view.